# URL routing in WCF/web service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to route the request coming to my WCF to a different web service(3.5framework).. Is this even possible? If yes, please let me know the steps.. 
I need to Route from http://example.com/OldService.svc/Route to http://Newexample.com/NewService.svc/Request

Below are few of the things i tried..Most of the google search returns the routing for webforms and my requirement is for WEB SERVICES.

I tried with the following in my OldService project customroute handler:  added a reference to the routing assembly, configured the web.config, added the below code in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteCollection routes = RouteTable.Routes;
        //routes.Add("SOAP",new Route("soap", new WebServiceRouteHandler("~/Services/SoapQuery.asmx")));
        routes.Add("SOAP", new Route("SOAP", new WebServiceRouteHandler("http://Newexample.com/NewService.svc/Request")));

    }
```

Added a WebServiceRouteHandler as below

```
 public class WebServiceRouteHandler: IRouteHandler
{
    private string _VirtualPath;

    public WebServiceRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        _VirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new WebServiceHandlerFactory().GetHandler(HttpContext.Current,
            "*",
            _VirtualPath,
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_VirtualPath));
    }
}
```

I m calling the oldservice but I m still not redirected to the new Service. Please let me know if i m missing anything here..Should i add anything in my OldService Route method?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by redirect.

Are you saying you would like the Web Service client to be redirected to a new Web Service end point when i tries to contact the old Web Service?

This is not typically possible as services don't have the concept of "redirection." Not to mention if you even tried to redirect to the new service your endpoint bindings would no longer match and the service wouldn't fire anyway.

Is it possible to have the old service call the new service itself and return the results?

Such as Client -> connects to old service -> old service connects to new service -> old service returns the new service results to the client.

You also need to ensure you are returning the exact schema back to the client as it expects based on the WSDL or you will find problems reading the response.

Not sure if this helps at all...

Comment: Thanks for the response..Yes i wanted to redirect from old service to New service..something like we have it in ASP.net url routing in web forms... If this is not possible, my last option would be to have the old service call the new service itself and return the results..

Comment: @Sahana sorry for the bad news but you are probably going to have to go with your last option as redirections are not possible with services in this nature.